# Ho to use Module Controller from Test Fragment loaded with Include Controller in Jemter

Tags: jmeter

I want to use reusable elements across my Jmeter scripts.

I’ve got [Include Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) which load [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) – for user journeys or common actions.

Test Fragment can still contain some repeatable elements. I was thinking about using [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) to reuse small elements in it. Module Controller works fine when I have it in my Test Script.

But when I try to use Module Controller in Test Fragment which will be included it returns me such error:

```
Error occurred starting thread group […] Module Controller has no selected Controller
```

It looks to me as Jmeter’s limitation.

Is there a way of using Module Controller within included Test Fragment? Or maybe I could use some better way for elements reusability.

Comment: your link states: When using Test Fragment with Module Controller, ensure you disable the Test Fragment to avoid the execution of Test Fragment itself. This is done by default since JMeter 2.13.

Comment: Disabling Test Fragment that is being included doesn't help in this situation unfortunately. My problem is that when you have Test Fragment in the other file - which you include to your test script, then Module Controller from that Test Fragment can't find element that it uses

Comment: Just stating It's a known Jmeter’s limitation in manual

Comment: I tried to use Module Controller within Test Fragment on JMeter 3.1, and had no problem, Module Controller within Test Fragment is triggered as expected. So can you share your configuration?

Comment: Hi @KirilS. I know it is an old question but I am using JMeter 4.0 and I cannot use Module controller within fragment. does anyone know if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Module Controller pointing to test fragment in Included scripts through Include Controller if I correctly understand question.

It's a limitation and is not anyway correctly displayed in UI.